# HoloLens 2 PV camera out of focus

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I am using HoloLens 2 :
The PV camera is often out of focus when I am staring at a very close object ( 30-40 cm from device).
How can I manually set the focus engine to the desired distance (I am not using spatial awareness)?
Thanks,

Eyal

I did not find any API to manually set the focus engine of the PV camera

Answer (score 0):

You can get a look at [VideoDeviceController Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Devices.VideoDeviceController?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-22000) to learn how to get or set the camera's focus setting.

Comment: Thanks, but this option is not working. It is not available in unity.  I added WinRT using this guide : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/using-the-windows-namespace-with-unity-apps-for-hololens
but it does not include a reference to the media device namespace

Comment: Have you tried [Conditionally include WinRT API calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/using-the-windows-namespace-with-unity-apps-for-hololens#conditionally-include-winrt-api-calls)? With this method, you should be able to use any WinRT APIs.